# Can I use the changes package to highlight added environments, say, itemize?

Tags: environments, changes

I am using `changes` package to track modifications to a LaTeX documents, but found simply wrapping `\begin{itemize}\end{itemize}` with `\added` command doesn't work. It works fine if I wrap the contents of each `itemize` separately.

Comment: The docs say (section "Limitations") that you can't use `\added` to wrap tables and figures and that it sometimes fails when you wrap more than one paragraph. I think it fails with item lists for the same reason. As a workaround, the docs suggest to put the multi-paragraph content into an external file and then use `\added{\include{...}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Having had issues with embedded environments using the changes package, I have found that the following works for `\replaced` and `\added`.

Use `\protect\input{<the external file name>}`. `\include{...}` provides a new page, which is not useful in a page of text.

Answer (score -1):

Including multiple paragraphs seems to work if they are separated by `\\ \\` instead of a blank line, as follows :

```
\added{para 1
\\\\ \\\\
para 2
\\\\ \\\\
para 3}
```